# Invalid Type of Response from api

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, axios, http-post

I have an issue while trying to use an api with my rest API but i have greek responses from names etc. I cant find out what is happening. I tried default post request but i got this response '� & � ������������ ����' i tried encodeURI but same thing happend i tried also to encodeURI the response data but i got response like that %5Bobject%20Object%5D.
The simple code i wrote.

```
   const axios = require('axios');

const data ={
    'datas for api'
}

var encoded_url = encodeURI(api)
axios.post(encoded_url, data, {
  headers: {
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
},
}).then(resData=>{
    console.log(encodeURI(resData))
})
```

Comment: this seems like an issue with format could you try to do the same call with postman to show us the response? also, DATA should be a MAP/JSON if you send a String like that it will fail

Comment: @Grismak using postman the response is normal and also tried the same code with python and it worked too only here i have issue. Also my data is json object dont worry i just remove them cause its private infos